# Why Does the FormClosed Event Handler Get Called Twice?

Tags: c#, winforms

StackOverflow may not be the correct place to as a why question, but I am looking for a because answer rather than a how to answer. I have already worked around the problem by disabling the handler in the hander.

The application has a DataGridView that displays inventory information during incoming inspection. The data grid is too wide for the screen and requires horizontal scrolling. To make the data easier to see and edit a modal editor has been added. There are 2 buttons to close the modal editor, either Save or Cancel. Using the close button at the top right corner of the modal editor form should perform the same action as the cancel button.

When the cancel button is clicked everything works fine. When the close button is clicked the modal editor FormClosed event fire twice. Why is the modal editor FormClosed event firing twice? Do I have a bug in my code?

```
    private bool CancelModalEditor()
    {
        bool cancelled = false;

        string cancelMsg = (_cancelClicked) ? "Canceling" : "Closing";
        cancelMsg += " the editor will delete the Record with Serial Number: " + SerialNumber + " from the Audit Session. Is this what you want to do?";

        DialogResult dlg = MessageBox.Show(cancelMsg, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dlg == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            SaveClicked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cancelled = true;
        }

        return cancelled;
    }

    private void AEMEBtn_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancelClicked = true;
        if (!CancelModalEditor())
        {
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            _cancelClicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void AEModalEditor_FormClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_cancelClicked && !SaveClicked)
        {
            if (CancelModalEditor())
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _cancelClicked = true;      // Prevent Infite Loop
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

File where modal editor is invoked.

```
    private void ModalEditorForm_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        AEModalEditor modalEditor = (AEModalEditor)sender;
        int currentRow = modalEditor.RowID - 1;

        if (modalEditor.SaveClicked)
        {
            UpdateDataGridRowWithModalEditorValues(dgAssetDetails, currentRow, modalEditor.AssetControlsValues);
            updateAuditDetailsDataGridRow(currentRow, modalEditor.AuditControlsValues);
            UpdateAuditTextFields(modalEditor);
            SelectAllCellsInRow(currentRow);
        }
        else
        {
            DeleteRowFromAllDataGridViews(modalEditor.SerialNumber, currentRow);
            _previouslySelectedRow = -1;
        }

        // Save all records in either case so that session data isn't lost.
        save(false);

        _currentlySelectedDataGrid = DataGrids.None;
        _modalEditorOpen = false;
        txtSerialNumber.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: dont call close again.

Comment: @DanielA.White as far as I know I'm only calling it once.

Comment: Yes you do. In `AEModalEditor_FormClosing` the Form is already closing (for whatever reason). Then you call `Close()` again in the else branch. Why? Just let it finish.

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry, I changed the code based on your comment and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call close in the closing-event again. The form is already closing and don't need to be closed a second time.

```
private void AEModalEditor_FormClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_cancelClicked && !SaveClicked)
    {
        if (CancelModalEditor())
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _cancelClicked = true;
            // You called Close here again
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```